# PyQt5.5 and Qt5 licence issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to install PyQt5.5 but I get this error

```
Error: This version of PyQt5 and the commercial version of Qt have incompatible licenses.
```

my `qtdetail.out` give this

```
Builder Qt
shared
```

I have installed `Qt5.5 open source` version.

Any idea how to install this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed both packages as open source, so I don't know what kind of incompatibilities there are, I guess it's a bug, anyway I found my way to install it.

You can just go in configure.py and comment off lines from 2591 to 2594. Then try to relaunch it.

These are the lines I commented off:

```
    if introspecting and target_config.qt_licensee != 'Open Source' and ltype == 'GPL':
        error(
                "This version of PyQt5 and the commercial version of Qt have "
                "incompatible licenses.")
```

Comment: Show what is in the lines 2591 to 2594